# Make Recorded TV Appear in Windows 7 Libraries/ Change library Icon

Tags: windows-7, icons, libraries

The Library Recorded TV exists, as you can add it to the right side of the Windows 7 Start Menu, but It doesn't appear in the Libraries Folder? ***Is it possible to make it appear there?*** I went to start menu, properties, customize to show the Recorded TV library on the right side of the start menu and changed: name of the library and directories it was linked to; to kind of add a custom item to the menu. I discovered a way to change the icon on libraries, but only the ones that appeared in the Library drop down of the explorer window. Therefore, I was wondering If there were alternatives to this method as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out as I remembered that this was possible but had forgotten since I had Windows 7. You basically need to navigate to C:\Users\Public\Libraries and copy the file/shortcut you see for Recorded TV and paste that into the respective user location for libraries, which is C:\Users{Name}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're talking about this and i'm doing this under windows 7 ultimate not sure if it matters, anyway...

[image]

Step 1: create New library

[image]

Step 2: name library

[image]

Step 3: include folder

[image]

Comment: Nope, I did not mean to create another Library; The recorded TV library is already present by default. Just wondering if there was a method to make the Library appear on the drop down list. The Recorded TV Library is only visible in Explorer after a configuration of a TV Tuner from within Media Center. Wondering If there was a way to bypass that.

Comment: what on earth are you talking about, can you please REFINE your question and post pictures.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, not sure why Microsoft left it out of libraries.
If navigate in windows explorer to "C:\Users\Public\Libraries" right click on "Recorded TV"  and click copy.
Then navigate to "C:\Users{your use name}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries" and click paste.

You now can see the Recorded TV library in explorer under Libraries.

Answer (score -1):

This got voted down with no reason why. Any criticism welcome, but I can't improve my answer if I don't know what's wrong with it.

Posted this as, in my experience, the above methods fail in achieving the desired setup - recycling the RecordedTV public library, so that it appears in the Users Library.

I've tried junctions, symbolic links, and shortcuts - none work ,so you have to move the folder, and update the registry. Details below.

1) rename and move the library to your library folder, to yourFolder, ie
 %appdata%\microsoft\windows\libraries

2) @ HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
update the absolute path of your new library, ie change the value for

{1A6FDBA2-F42D-4358-A798-B74D745926C5} to

C:\Users\you\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries\NEW.library-ms

3) now you've got the library, but you can only include via properties (right-click on the startpanel link). To fix, update the FolderDescription for the RecordedTv library, @

HKLM\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions{1A6FDBA2-F42D-4358-A798-B74D745926C5}

I changed the (value for) "Parent" folder to

{1B3EA5DC-B587-4786-B4EF-BD1DC332AEAE}

(ie your libraries folder, in %appdata%\roaming....Windows)

I then added the Parsing Name

::{031E4825-7B94-4dc3-B131-E946B44C8DD5}{1A6FDBA2-F42D-4358-A798-B74D745926C5}

like the Music library,

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions{2112AB0A-C86A-4ffe-A368-0DE96E47012E})

[image: here's the library, along with the other libraries, plus downloads, userfolder, MyLinks is Favorites, but going to users\Links]

[image: here's the 'My System' library in the 'Include in Library' menu]

Hope that helps :)